# remove spaces from string PHP and insert to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to remove spaces from string but only from beggining and end of the string. Everythink work fine but after insert string to database there is no spaces but in the same place is "�".

Here is my code:

```
$synonimy = $_POST['fsynoms'];
$synonimyPodzielone = explode( ',', $synonimy );
for($k=0; $k < count($synonimyPodzielone); $k++)
{
    for($m=0; $m<strlen($synonimyPodzielone[$k]);$m++)
    {

        if($synonimyPodzielone[$k][$m]==" ")
        {
            $synonimyPodzielone[$k][$m]="";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tryied with str_replace trim and same problem.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: use PHP Trim function?

Comment: � looks like an type encoding problem..

Comment: Yes it could be but before removing spaces it works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`trim`](http://php.net/trim). With the help of [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) you can even skip the for loop.

```
$input = " foo , bar , baz , qux ";
$words = explode(",", $input);
$wordsTrimmed = array_map("trim", $words);
$csvString = implode(",", $wordsTrimmed);

echo $csvString; // foo,bar,baz,qux
```

You can of course make it neater:

```
function trimWords($string, $glue = ",") {
    return implode($glue, array_map("trim", explode($glue, $string)));
}

$input = " foo , bar , baz , qux ";
$csvString = trimWords($input);

echo $csvString; // foo,bar,baz,qux
```

Comment: yes but what if there is 

$input = " foo , bar two   , baz , qux"
and i want to keep word "bar two" no bartwo

Comment: @krystian Trim only removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The `trim($str)` function ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php ) is hard to use incorrectly, were you just not storing the return value? (the `trim` function in PHP does not modify the argument, it instead returns a new string with whitespace removed).

```
$synonimy = $_POST['fsynoms'];
$synonimy = trim( $synonimy );

insert_into_database( $synonimy );
```

Comment: yes but if i have an array with strings like:
$tab=['word1', '   word2  ', word-part1  word-part2 '];

i want to remove spaces only before word and after word no between word-part1 and word-part2;

Answer (score 1):

PHP Trim: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php should make life much easier.

```
for($m=0; $m<strlen($synonimyPodzielone[$k]);$m++)
{
    $synonimyPodzielone[$k][$m] = trim($synonimyPodzielone[$k][$m]);    
}
```

Comment: yes i have tryied it and it work but after insert string to database in place of spaces are "��".

Example i want to put word : Hello  but before Hello are two spaces i want to remove it and use trim. After that there is ��

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler.

```
$synonimy = trim($_POST['fsynoms']);
insert_into_database($synonimy);
```

Answer (score 0):

using strtr is also possible (and fast):

```
$synonimy = trim($_POST['fsynoms']);
$synonimy = strtr($synonimy, array(' ,' => ',', ', '=>','));
```

Note: if your string contains duplicate spaces you want to remove, in this case you can use this:

```
$synonimy = preg_replace('~\s*(,)\s*|\A\s+|\s+\z~u', '$1', $_POST['fsynoms']);
```

that deals with unicode strings.